# Java delimiter reading a text file

Tags: java, arrays, delimiter

I'm trying to read a text file with this format:

```
Array x
1,3,5,4

Array y
12,13,15,11
```

and put it in two array, but I only want the integer.
What delimiter should I use to ignore the String and the empty line?

Here's my code in putting the int to arrays. By the way, I'm using scanner to read the file:

```
Scanner sc = null;

     try
     {
     sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C:\\x.txt"));
     sc.useDelimiter("");  // What will I put inside a quote to get only the int values?
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
     System.out.println("file not found!");
     }
int[] xArray = new int[4];
int[] yArray = new int[4];

     while (sc.hasNextInt( )){
         for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            xArray[i] = sc.nextInt( );
        }
         for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            yArray[i] = sc.nextInt( );
        }
    }
```

What I want to get is

```
int[] xArray = {1,3,5,4}
int[] yArray = {12,13,15,11}
```

I hope you understand :)

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use `nextLine()` and use the `split` method to parse each `int`?

Comment: Also, in the while, you loose the first int read in the condition while (sc.hasNextInt( )){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use bufferedreader instead of scanner. You can use below code :

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your file name"));
br.readLine(); //it will omit first line Array x
String x=br.readLine(); //it return second line as a string
String[] x_value=x.split(","); //You can parse string array into int.
```

This is for Array x. You can do the same for array y. and after that parse into int.